# Degrees of belief without evidence

Tags: belief

I'm not sure this is really a philosophy question.

Suppose that I have some evidence that my wife is having an affair, but it *all* dates back to a year ago. How do I incorporate the lack of evidence she still doing so, in deciding how likely she is still involved with this person?

For the sake of argument, suppose my degree of belief she was having an affair is 80%, and half of affairs last long enough that her affair would not have ended. So I would suspect, ceteris paribus, with about 40% certainty she is still having this affair, if not for the complete lack of evidence she is.

How certain can I be? Surely not 40%; wouldn't the lack of evidence it is still ongoing count as evidence that it has ended, but if so how is that quantified?

Comment: What is my degree of belief that not_me_either = thinkingman?

Comment: hahah not at all @Frank

Comment: I was taught that extrapolation based on old data is bad science. Just look her in the eyes and ask her point blank about the affair.

Comment: And be ready to be slapped :-)

Comment: thanks for the comment @SteveSaban can you define 'old data' for me? it has some bearing on my internal life (caveat i'm unmarried)